# Why does GetObject fail here when lbvobject is NULL

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

The `GetObject()` documentation says that when `lpvObject` is NULL, the function returns the number of bytes required.  But, I am getting 0, which is the return value when it fails.

I've been searching and trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've just got a basic window setup using the `WM_PAINT` message:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    HBITMAP hbmap;
    hbmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, str_path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    BITMAP bm;
    HDC bmapmemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    SelectBitmap(bmapmemory, hbmap);
    int a = GetObject(hbmap, sizeof(BITMAP), NULL);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 750, 750, bmapmemory, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    char c[64];
    sprintf_s(c, sizeof(c), "%f\n", a);
    OutputDebugStringA(c);

    DeleteDC(bmapmemory);
    DeleteObject(bmap);

    EndPaint(hwnd,& ps);

    return 0;
}
```

As I said, `a` is always 0, or failure, for the `GetObject()` function call.

Comment: Is `hbitmap` actually a valid handle? Likely not. First, check to see if it's non-NULL. If so, check `GetLastError` after the call to `LoadImage`. (It is sort of strange that the variable is usually spelled `hbmap` except in the call to `GetObject`, where you spell it `hbitmap`. I assume that's just a typo, but typos should be impossible when copying and pasting *real code* into your Stack Overflow question...)

Comment: Did you mean "hbmap"?

Comment: Yes I did mean hbmap, it was a typo when I was getting rid of some unrelated stuff. Edited thanks. Thats the weird part is that the handle is created sucessfully and non null, and blts onto the screen properly and everything.

Comment: You don't do any error checking and %f is the wrong format string. And this isn't the actual code since you didn't paste it. So who knows what's going on. An mcve would remove doubt.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `"%f"` format but passing an integer. That's undefined behavior. If you look at the return value in the debugger you'll probably find that it's *not* zero.